# Cycle SkewX to increase and decrease

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way that this code can cycle.

Let me explain, the element should increase up to a maximum (ex. skewX (500deg)) and then go back to a minimum (ex. skewX (100deg)), do you already know a way?
This is my html:

```
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html customSpanToBorder">
<div class="wpb_wrapper" style="transform: skewX(0deg);"> 
<span class="customLineServizi"> </span>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my jquery:

```
var sdegree = 0;

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        sdegree ++ ;
        sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;
        var srotate = "skewX(" + sdegree + "deg)";

        jQuery(".customSpanToBorder .wpb_wrapper").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
    });
```

Comment: use @keyframes animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this repeat indefinitely then using CSS `@keyframes` would be the most appropriate solution. After defining the animation you can set the `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite`. Try this:

```css
.customSpanToBorder .wpb_wrapper {
  background-color: #C00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: skewX(0deg);
  animation-name: skew;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes skew {
  50% {
    transform: skewX(500deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewX(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html customSpanToBorder">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper" style="transform: skewX(0deg);">
    <span class="customLineServizi"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```